# Java ScheduledFuture executing asynchronous task wait until completed

Tags: java, concurrency, jakarta-mail, scheduling, scheduledexecutorservice

In order to asynchronously send large emails at a fixed rate, i'm using an `ScheduledExecutorService`.

I have a class implementing `Runnable`, that asynchronously sends a mail. It needs to be called every second and exactly x times. For the actual sending I use [Simple Java Mail](http://www.simplejavamail.org/#/about). The method I call is `EmailBuilder#send(mail, /* boolean async */ true)`.

Once this method has been called those x times, `ScheduledExecutorService#shutdown()` is called.

What I would like, is being able to determine at which point in time all scheduled Runnables have terminated, i.e., all `EmailBuilder#send(mail, /* boolean async */ true)` calls have returned.

I tried `ScheduledExecutorService#awaitTermination()` with some timeout and also `ScheduledFuture#get()`, but it didn't work or some exception has been thrown.

```
package playground;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.simplejavamail.email.Email;
import org.simplejavamail.email.EmailBuilder;
import org.simplejavamail.mailer.Mailer;
import org.simplejavamail.mailer.MailerBuilder;

public class MCVE {

    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;
    private SendTask sd;
    private ScheduledFuture<?> sf;
    private boolean terminateFlag = false;

    public void start() {
        sd = new SendTask();
        scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        sf = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(sd, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    private class SendTask implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Mailer mailer = MailerBuilder.withSMTPServer("smtp.gogglemail.com", 587).buildMailer();

            Email mail = EmailBuilder.startingBlank()
                .from("from@gmail.com")
                .to("to@gmail.com")
                .withSubject("Subject")
                .withPlainText("Content")
                .buildEmail();

            mailer.sendMail(mail, /* async */ true);

            if (terminateFlag) {
                sf.cancel(true);
                scheduler.shutdown();
                return;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for some helpful advice!

Comment: You really need to add code, preferably an [mcve] .

Answer (score 0):

Collect all futures returned after scheduling in collection and then foreach get().

Comment: `ScheduledExecutorService#scheduleAtFixedRate()` returns only one `ScheduledFuture`. Calling `get()` throws a `CancellationException`.

Comment: If you schedule at fixed rate, when do you expect all the tasks to complete?, it will repeat for eternity

Comment: No, because the `ScheduledExecutorService` is shutdown, therefore the program execution will terminate.

Answer (score 0):

What about sf.isCancelled()? It is not what you are looking for?

Comment: No, because `ScheduledFuture#cancel()` is called after the sending of all mails has started, but since they're send asynchronously, it is not clear, whether the send process really is complete. So `ScheduledFuture#isCancelled()` will return `true` before the all mails have been sent (completely) if sending takes more time than the period/rate passed to `ScheduledExecutorService#scheduleAtFixedRate()`.

Comment: Your SendTask already async called from your main program. Why you call mailer's async and then want to get know when it completes? U can make that call sync, remove terminated part and use method as mentoined by @Eddie